# Why does the Availability property from Win32_PnPEntity return -1 for all USB devices?

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I am trying to get the availability status from a PnP device
I have read through this article: [Win32_PnPEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-pnpentity) , and it seems like I should be able to get the value; however it always comes up null and I can't figure out why. Other properties like "Name", "Caption", "ClassGUID", etc are returning good values.

Here is some code showing what I'm trying to do...

```cs
using System.Management;


using var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Description LIKE '%USB%'");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for CmdPort to be available...");

foreach (var device in collection)
{
    var availableTimeout = 50;
    var name = device["Name"];
    Console.WriteLine($"Checking availability for: {name}");
    while (availableTimeout > 0)
    {
        var availability = device["Availability"] ?? -1;
        if ((int)availability == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Device [{name}] is available");
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Availability = {availability} (timeout = {availableTimeout})");

         availableTimeout--;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting availability to come back with a uint16 between 1 and 21

Comment: The simple truth about WMI is that implementations are not guaranteed to return values..

Comment: what is `device` ?(I'm guessing this is some instance of  `ManagementObject`)

Comment: Oops, yes I left out the foreach loop in my snippet that was wrapped around that code, Fixed it in the edit